# Send Email from TableView in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tableview

I have a TableView set to trigger a different ViewController when the user selects an item in the list, but I would like "Contact Us" to trigger the Messages Framework (In App Email) so the user can send an email and not get pushed to a ViewController.

Any suggestions? Below is a block of code that I'm using for "Contact Us".

Sorry if this is an obvious answer, learning as I go and envy all you wizards out there!

```
 NSMutableDictionary *sectionContactUs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [sectionContactUs setObject:kSlideViewControllerSectionTitleNoTitle forKey:kSlideViewControllerSectionTitleKey];
    [sectionContactUs setObject:@"Contact Us" forKey:kSlideViewControllerSectionTitleKey];
    NSMutableDictionary *contactUsViewControllerDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [contactUsViewControllerDictionary setObject:@"Contact Us" forKey:kSlideViewControllerViewControllerTitleKey];
    [contactUsViewControllerDictionary setObject:@"ContactUsViewController" forKey:kSlideViewControllerViewControllerNibNameKey];
    [contactUsViewControllerDictionary setObject:[ContactUsViewController class] forKey:kSlideViewControllerViewControllerClassKey];
    [sectionTest setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:contactUsViewControllerDictionary] forKey:kSlideViewControllerSectionViewControllersKey];
    [datasource addObject:sectionContactUs];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MFMailComposeComposeView:
 First Import `MessageUI` framework in your project
And write `#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>` in your view controller also add `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` at interface

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test1@gmail.com", @"test2@gmail.com", nil]; 
[controller setToRecipients:toRecipients];
[controller setTitle:@"Contact Us"];
[controller setSubject:@"Your Mail Subject"];
[controller setMessageBody:@"Mail body here \n Comments" isHTML:NO];

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
}
else
{
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
}
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Also add this methods

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    NSString *strMailResult;
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            strMailResult = NSLocalizedString(@"E-Mail Cancelled",@"");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            strMailResult = NSLocalizedString(@"E-Mail Saved",@"");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            strMailResult = NSLocalizedString(@"E-Mail Sent",@"");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            strMailResult = NSLocalizedString(@"E-Mail Failed",@"");
            break;
        default:
            strMailResult = NSLocalizedString(@"E-Mail Not Sent",@"");
            break;
    }

    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Message",@"") message:strMailResult delegate:self  cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"") otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can open MFMailComposeViewController for send mail..

```
-(void)doEmail
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate =self;


    [picker setMessageBody:@"Body message" isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
}


- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
//////nslog (@"mail finished");
}
```

Comment: Make sure you add the delegate to the .h file: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate